# Sum 10 numbers and print result in NASM

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I have written following assembly code for adding 10 numbers.I am able to compile it and execute it but I am getting wrong result.
I just wanted to know how do I print the value of **total** on scree.

```
section .data
num1: dw 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50
total: dw 0
msg :  db "sum=%d",10,0

section .text
    extern _printf
    global _main
_main:
    push ebp
    mov ebp,esp
    mov ebx,num1 ;point bx to first number
    mov ecx,10      ;load count of numbers in ecx
    mov eax,0       ;initialize sum to zero
loop:
    add eax,[ebx]
    add ebx,2
    sub ecx,1
    jnz loop
    mov [total],eax

    push total
    push msg
    call _printf

    pop ebp
    mov esp,ebp
    ret
```

**solution**

```
section .data
num1: dd 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50,300
total: dd 0
msg :  dd "sum=%d",10,0

    section .text
        extern _printf
        global _main
    _main:
        push ebp
        mov ebp,esp
        mov ebx,num1 ;point bx to first number
        mov ecx,11     ;load count of numbers in ecx
        mov eax,0       ;initialize sum to zero
    loop:
        add eax,[ebx]
        add ebx,4
        sub ecx,1
        jnz loop
        mov  [total],eax
        push dword [total]

        push msg
        call _printf
        mov esp,ebp
        pop ebp

        ret
```

Comment: What "wrong result" do you get ?

Comment: @PaulR:I am getting grabage value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a couple of issues here. First, you've got `num1` and `total` declared as `dw`. `dw` may sound like it means "dword", but it means "data word". You want these to be `dd` - "data dword"... since that's how you're using them. (and `add ebx, 4` not 2) If you really need to use word (16-bit) values in 32-bit code, it can be done, but is awkward.

The second problem I see is that `push total` before your `call _printf` pushes the address of `total`. You want the "[contents]" of memory here, so `push dword [total]`. (`push msg` is correct)

After this, you probably want `add esp, 8` (I like to write it as `add esp, 4 * 2` - two parameters of 4 bytes each). It is possible to "defer" this stack cleanup - `mov esp, ebp` will fix you up, but it needs to be done BEFORE the `pop ebp`!!!

... there may be more...

Answer (score 3):

You are using 32-bit memory access to work with 16-bit values.

Each element of the array is 16 bits wide. However, since `eax` is 32 bits wide, the following treats the array as if each element was also 32 bits wide:

```
add eax,[ebx]
```

The following also isn't quite correct, for exactly the same reason:

```
mov [total],eax
```

I think there's also an issue whereby you're pushing the *address* of `total` before calling `printf()`, whereas you should probably be pushing its *value*.

Also, as pointed out by @JasonD, you need to clean up the stack after calling `printf()`.

Finally, the

```
mov esp,ebp
```

instruction should be removed as all it does is corrupt your stack pointer.

Comment: @JasonD: Oh yeah, I forgot about that. I'll add a note to the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**dw** defines 16-bit entities but `add eax,[ebx]` is adding 32-bit entities. Either change **dw** to **dd** or put **WORD PTR** before **[ebx]**. Also, as NPE points out, you need to change how you handle storing **eax** into **total**.